# Prove that the expectation of the number of black balls preceding the first white ball is $\frac {b}{w+1}$

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Balls are taken one by one out of an urn containing $w$ white and $b$ black balls until the first white ball is drawn. Prove that the expectation of the number of black balls preceding the first white ball is $\frac {b}{w+1}$

**Attempt:** Let $X_i$ be the random variable that denotes the number of black balls that are drawn at the $i_{th}$ step before a white ball is drawn.

Then, the total number of such balls $ X= X_1 +  \cdots+X_n \implies E(X)=\sum E(X_i).$

$E(X_i)= 1 \cdot \dfrac {^bC_i}{^{b+w}Cr}\cdot \dfrac {^wC_1}{^{b+w-r}C_1}$

Thus, $\sum E(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{b} ~ 1 \cdot \dfrac {^bC_i}{^{b+w}Ci}\cdot \dfrac {^wC_1}{^{b+w-i}C_1}$

Could someone please tell me if I attempted this correctly? Because I get a very complicated answer in the end after evaluating the above.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not cross-post across sites.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I will take care. Have been stuck for long on this problem. Could you give me a direction please?

Comment: You're working too hard.  By considering how things change when a black ball is withdrawn, it suffices to check that the formula is correct when $b=0$ and to verify that otherwise $$e_w(b) = \frac{b}{b+w}\left(1+e_w(b-1)\right)$$ where $e_w(b) = b/(w+1).$

Comment: @whuber I am a bit confused because of one conceptual problem. Does, the probability of finding a black ball at the $ith$ step remain the same as at every step? Shouldn't it change because at the $i-1~th$ step, a black ball could have been recovered? Thanks

Comment: For fixed $w,$ the probability of finding a black ball when the urn has $b$ black balls is $b/(b+w),$ no matter what $b$ may be.

Comment: @whuber Suppose at the $i-1 th$ step, a black ball has been recovered. How can the probability still remain the same as $\frac{b}{b+w}$? because the number of black balls has decreased now

Comment: It doesn't remain the same: the new number of black balls is $b-1=b^\prime,$ so the formula tells you the new chance of a black ball is $b^\prime/(b^\prime + w).$

Comment: @whuber which means probability of finding a black ball at the $ith $ step should be $\frac {b-1}{b-1+w}$?

Comment: @whuber Therefore, shouldn't we adjust the dynamic probabilities while finding the expectation??? Because at each step, the probability is changing

Comment: That's right, which is why "$e_w(b-1)$" appears in the recursion.

Comment: Answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404498/prove-that-the-expectation-of-the-number-of-black-balls-preceding-the-first-whit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mathematical induction.** It is easy to do @whuber's proof by [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to show
that with $w$ white balls and $b$ black ones in the urn, the number $X$ of black balls drawn before the first white one has $E(X) = \frac{b}{w+1}.$ [Start the induction step with $1 + e_w(b-1) = \frac{w+1}{w+1} + \frac{b-1}{w+1}.]$

**Simple case with seven balls in the urn.** Also, in the specific case where $w=2$ and $b = 5,$ simple combinatorial arguments show
that $P(X = k) = \frac{6-k}{21},$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, 5.$  [For example,
$P(X = 1) = \frac{2 \cdot 5}{7\cdot 6} = \frac{5}{21}.$]

Then you can use a calculator to find
$$E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^5 k\frac{6-k}{21} = \frac{b}{w+1} = \frac{5}{3} = 1.6667.$$

```
k = 0:5; sum(k*(6-k)/21)
[1] 1.666667
```

**Simulation of specific case.** A simulation in R of a million such experiments (drawing without replacement
and counting the draws before getting a white ball) approximates the
distribution of $X.$ [The R function `match` finds the draw with the first white ball (`1`). The `sample` function draws all the balls in sequence without replacement.]

```
set.seed(1022)
b = 5;  w = 2
balls = c(rep(0,b),rep(1,w))  # `0` for black, `1` for white
x = replicate(10^6, match(1,sample(balls))-1)
mean(x)
[1] 1.66686
b/(w+1)
[1] 1.666667
table(x)/10^6
x
       0        1        2        3        4        5 
0.286038 0.238137 0.189911 0.142529 0.095611 0.047774
```

These simulated probabilities are accurate to a couple of decimal places as
shown in the histogram below. Histogram bars show simulated probabilities and dots show exact ones.

[image]

*Note;* If balls were drawn ***with replacement,*** then $X$ would have a
[geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) distribution.